# Cant change Airflow executor from airflow.cfg

Tags: airflow

I have the default airflow.cfg file, haven't really changed anything except for the timezone. So my executor is set for the default SequentialExecutor.
However, my airflow scheduler always starts with the LocalExecutor which is weird.
I ran the following commands for debugging:

1. get airflow home directory.

```
airflow@a2c996fa1c61:/opt/airflow$ echo $AIRFLOW_HOME
/opt/airflow
```

2. cat airflow.cfg to find executor.

```
airflow@a2c996fa1c61:/opt/airflow$ cat /opt/airflow/airflow.cfg | grep "executor ="
executor = SequentialExecutor
```

3. get executor using airflow config list.

```
airflow@a2c996fa1c61:/opt/airflow$ airflow config list | grep "executor ="
executor = LocalExecutor
```

Can someone explain to me how the values from command 2 and 3 are different? also everytime I try to run `airflow scheduler` I get the following log.

```
[2023-04-17 13:06:55,693] {executor_loader.py:107} INFO - Loaded executor: LocalExecutor
```

Worth mentioning that I am running Airflow on Docker. And in my docker-compose file I have this line:
`AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: LocalExecutor`

Does this some sort of force the type of executor regardless of the config file?